# Equality of field extensions with same minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I am rather perturbed by this simple exercise. I have to show that

$F(\sqrt{a+b+2\sqrt{a b}})=F(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$

Now, I can see that these both elements are roots of $x^4-2(a+b)x^2+(a-b)^2$, which I can prove is irreducible over $F$. Okay, simple. But I can get only that

$F(\sqrt{a+b+2\sqrt{a b}})\cong F(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$

using basic theorem of field extensions. Also, I am pleased to say I understand

$\sqrt{a+b+2\sqrt{a b}}=\sqrt{(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2}$,

but I am unsure if I can think this way at all. I really fail to see how to show at least that one of those field extensions is the subset of other or something, which would, along with isomorphism imply equality. Please help or else I shall lose my mind (and time) over such simple thing! Of course, $a\neq b$, characteristic of $F$ is not $2$...

Comment: What is $F$? you didn't define it

Comment: $F$ is a field!

Comment: Just as a note about what you say in the end of your post : even if $K\subset L$  is a field extension, and if $K\simeq L$, one does not necessarily have $K=L$ (it is true if $[L:K] < \infty$ though)